# Using custom number formatting "#,##0.00" and "#.##0,00" in VBA produces unwanted results

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which removes all the formatting with:

```
Dim t as ListObject
For Each t In ActiveSheet.ListObjects
    t.DataBodyRange.ClearFormats
Next
```

When I debug, I then see that this clears also number formats for all the values which now look like this:

[image]

Then, another macro kicks in. It first checks what decimal and thousands sepparator system uses and according to this sets the *"custom format"* `format_1` like this:

```
Dim format_1 As String

If Application.DecimalSeparator = "." And Application.ThousandsSeparator = "," Then
    format_1 = "#,##0.00"
ElseIf Application.DecimalSeparator = "," And Application.ThousandsSeparator = "." Then
    format_1 = "#.##0,00"
End If
```

A couple of lines later `format_1` is applied like this:

```
Dim t as ListObject
For Each t in ActiveSheet
    t.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = format_1
Next
```

And I get a desired result:

[image]

Now this all works while my *"thousands separator"* is `,` and *"decimal separator"* is `.`:

[image]

Then I change my settings by swapping *"thousands separator"* to `.` and *"decimal separator"* to `,`:

[image]

Before both of the macros run it looks good because `,` is where `.` was previously:

[image]

Then I run my macros and first one clears all the formatting as it should:

[image]

But second one messes things up completely. I get the weird result which I can not explain to myself:

[image]

I was expecting two decimal places here... What am I doing wrong with `"#,##0.00"` and `"#.##0,00"` custom number formatting? This is the official documentation ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)). Some examples can also be found in Excel where we can right click the cell and select *"Format Cells"*, then under the *"Number"* tab, we can also see some of the examples *(which is what I used)*:

[image]

I tried to changing system locale in the control panel from `United States` and `English (United States)` to `Slovenia` and `English (Slovenia)`.

[image]

[image]

and this is where things get really really weird after the second macro runs! The decimal character just disappears, but only on some of the columns!? What was previously `0.429448068141937` or `0,429448068141937` is now `429448068141937`, but here the value really changed, not just how it is displayed...

[image]

Comment: If I use `"#,##0.00"` for both, there are errors...

Comment: Try using the built-in sty.e "comma", by using `t.DataBodyRange.Style="comma"` instead of using the custom format string. This will automatically use whatever you have set in the Excel options without you needing to check them.

Comment: @JohnRC There is no style `"comma"`. They are `"General"`, `"Percentage"`, `"Number"`... But none of these enables me to set exactly 2 decimal digits.

Comment: OK, in that case, go to Home>Styles>v > New cell style... > give it the name "comma" (or whatever you like) > Format... > Number > Check [_] Use 1000 Separator and set Decimal Places to [2] > OK > OK to save the new style. Then you can use that new style name.

Comment: @JohnRC A can't solve this problem like this because I am developing simultaneously for two customers. One has "thousands separator" is `,` and "decimal separator" is `.` while the other has vice versa. And I don't want end users to deal with creating their own styles. Solution needs to work on it's own.

Comment: Why won't you set the `application.decimalseparator = "."` , apply formating and then change separator back to comma, if needed? Just a quick workaround.

Comment: Actually, in my excel `.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"` works same for both separators, have a try without checking `If Application.DecimalSeparator = "."` , just apply `.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"` to numbers with different separators. 
As far as I know, '.' is typical separator for vba and when you use format `"#.##0,00"` (with comma) vba formats values s text.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way, which should work for both cases (`Decimal` and `Thousands` separators):

```
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
   rng.NumberFormat = Format("#,###.00", "Standard")
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it

Comment: Hey! This did not solve the problem. It is the same as it was.

Comment: @71GA I cannot understand what's happening in your system. I changed the two separators and the above code works well for both cases...

Comment: I just checked and it seems that Slovenian locale *(if I set it from the Windows control panel)* sets  *"thousands separator"* and *"decimal separator"* both to `.`! It must be a Microsoft bug! I double checked it with `Debug.Print Application.ThousandsSeparator` and `Debug.Print Application.ThousandsSparator`... Version of Excel is `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20148) 64-bit `

Comment: @71GA I think that what you say is extremely improbable... 1. I think/hope that is a typo in your comment and you checked 'DecimalSeparator`, too. Then,  `Application.ThousandsSeparator` and `Application.DecimalSeparator` are not so eloquent related to language localization. Please, try `Debug.Print Application.International(xlThousandsSeparator), Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator)`. Most probably it will return different separators. They are `readOnly` properties, since the one you used can be modified by code. You probably played with (only) one of them and that's why they look so

Comment: @71GA I can see in the pictures you show that your SO language is English. So, if you have TeanViewer or AnyDesk installed and accept a connection, I will like to see what's happening in your installation and better understand what is it about...